Get most recent using datetime
I have following table -



Table
Status
Code
Timestamp




Budget
Success
access
03-02-2024T08:04:23.19Z


Property
Failed
access
03-02-2024T08:04:23.19Z


Transfer
Success
access
03-02-2024T08:04:23.19Z


Property
Success
access
03-02-2024T08:04:23.19Z


Load
Success
access
03-02-2024T00:07:02.54Z


Property
Failed
access
03-02-2024T00:07:02.54Z


Transfer
Success
uprow
03-02-2024T00:07:02.54Z


Load
Success
uprow
01-02-2024T18:17:54.42Z


Property
Failed
uprow
01-02-2024T18:17:54.42Z


Transfer
Success
uprow
01-02-2024T18:17:54.42Z



I want recent timestamp for each of the table, where code is 'access'. This is independent of the status. Please suggest a sql query.



Table
Status
Code
Timestamp




Budget
Success
access
03-02-2024T08:04:23.19Z


Property
Failed
access
03-02-2024T08:04:23.19Z


Transfer
Success
access
03-02-2024T08:04:23.19Z


Load
Success
access
03-02-2024T00:07:02.54Z




What RDBMS are you using, MySQL, SQL-Server, Postgres, Oracle, etc? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql?rq=1 for MySQL/MariaDB.

Thank you. Currently on Snowflake select.

This should work for most modern databases:
WITH Numbered AS (
    select "Table", Status, Code, Timestamp
        , row_number() over (partition by "Table" order by Timestamp desc) rn
    from "MyTable"
    where Code = 'access'
)
SELECT "Table", Status, Code, Timestamp
FROM Numbered
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY Timestamp DESC

But be careful: some databases still in common use that might seem modern aren't actually up to modern standards, such as Access or MySQL 5.7.
You can see it work here for any supported version of the associated database:

SQL Server
Postgres
MySQL
SQLite

The only difference between them is the data type for the TimeStamp column and MySQL won't use ANSI object delimiters.
But tell us what database you're using next time, because often the differences are more significant.

When talking about standards, to be 100% ISO/IEC 9075-2 compliant: TIMESTAMP is a reserved word, needs to be delimited. And, as a note, both T611, Elementary OLAP operations and T121, WITH (excluding RECURSIVE) in query expression are optional features.

@Joel Thank you, solution works. I am on snowflake select, so I did not write RDBMS, but yes, it takes mySQL and native SQL.

Well snowflake is it's own kind of special, and commonly does things very different from your garden-variety rdbms. All the more reason to include that info in the question.
